# Is it possible to create rotationally symmetric Venn diagrams with 7 sets?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to construct a two-dimensional Venn diagram with 7 sets. The examples I found on-line do not have rotational symmetry, so they are rather confusing to use. Is there a way to construct these in a way which is rotationally symmetrical?

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a rotationally symmetric Venn diagram which divides the region into $2^n$ regions, the article [here](http://www.combinatorics.org/files/Surveys/ds5/VennSymmExamples.html) addresses it for the case $n=7$.

Here is one such rotationally symmetric Venn diagram taken from [here](http://www.combinatorics.org/files/Surveys/ds5/gifs/GrunSymm7.gif).
[image]

---

Typically, though when I think of a rotationally symmetric Venn diagram with $n$ sets, I would construct $n$ circles, where the $k^{th}$ circle is given by
$$(x- r\cos(k \theta))^2 + (y-r\sin(k \theta))^2 \leq cr^2$$
where $\theta = \dfrac{2 \pi}n$ and $k \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$. Below is one such construction with $c = 1.5$ for $n=7$. However, as Martin rightly points out in the comments, this doesn't divide the region into $2^n$ distinct sub-regions.
[image]

PS: The figure was done with grapher on Mac OS X

Comment: Isn't a Venn diagram supposed to have $2^n$ regions?

Comment: @Martin Thanks for pointing that out. I did not know that in a Venn diagram, we needed to have all the $2^n$ regions i.e. I did not know the difference between the Venn diagram and the Euler diagram. This is a good piece of information to know. Thanks.